# JavaFX: method and return dosen't seems to work in the proper way

Tags: java, javafx, return

'Morning.
I just have a little problem whit java FX.
The problem is this: i want to write a code and let a pop up come when use will close up the application via default close button.

```
package sample;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Button button;
    boolean answer=false;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        window=primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Homepage");
        window.setOnCloseRequest(e-> {
            e.consume();
            close();
        });
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300,300);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
private void close(){ answer = ConfirmationBox.display("close app", "'sure about that?");
if(answer) {
    System.out.println(answer);
    window.close();
}
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

every time i press the default kill app button, a pop up message will follow and ask me if i want to close the app

```
 public static boolean display(String titolo,String messaggio){
        Stage window = new Stage();
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle(titolo);
        Label label=new Label();
        label.setText(messaggio);


        Button yButton = new Button("yes");
        Button nButton = new Button("no");

        yButton.setOnAction(e-> {
            flag=true;
            window.close();
        });

        nButton.setOnAction(e-> {
            flag=false;
            window.close();
        });

        VBox layout = new VBox(20);
        layout.minHeight(250);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label,yButton,nButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout,300,300);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        return flag;
```

The issue is, when i run for the first time the method, the boolean variable "answer" did not propely save the result, so the close(), can't rly enter inside the if case.
how to prevent this? did i miss some javaFX funcionality? i'm new about javaFX and java itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Exit Application");
            alert.setContentText("Do you want to exit?");

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();

            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() != ButtonType.OK) {
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Window.show()` method shows the window *and returns immediately*. Therefore your code

```
public static boolean display(String titolo,String messaggio){

    // ...

    window.show();

    return flag;
}
```

will display the window and immediately return the current value of `flag` (which is initially `false`).

If the user presses the `yButton`, the flag is *then* set to `true`, and the next time they attempt to close the main window, the method immediately returns `true` and the main window closes.

You can instead use the method [`window.showAndWait()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait()) which "Shows this stage and waits for it to be hidden (closed) before returning to the caller.":

```
public static boolean display(String titolo,String messaggio){

    // ...

    // window.show();
    window.showAndWait();

    return flag;
}
```

As other answers have pointed out, there is also a [`Dialog` API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), including a convenience [`Alert` class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html). The main functionality that `Dialog` provides that a plain `Stage` doesn't is the ability to return a value from the `showAndWait()` method. In your case, you want to return a `boolean`, so the `Dialog`-based version of your method would look like:

```
public static boolean display(String titolo,String messaggio){

    Dialog<Boolean> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle(titolo);
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContentText(messaggio);
    dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(
        ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);

    // Result of dialog is true if button is YES button, 
    // false otherwise
    dialog.setResultConverter(button -> button == ButtonType.YES);

    // return result of dialog, or false if there is no result
    // (i.e. if user closes dialog without pressing a button)
    return dialog.showAndWait().orElse(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Java myself, so I understand perfectly where you are now.

What I'm guessing is that your main method keeps running after the confirmation dialog appears, so answer is still false that first time. Maybe you have to keep your main method waiting while the user is still considering whether or not to close the program.

If your ConfirmationBox class extends the DialogPane class, you can use the method `window.showAndWait()` instead of `window.show()` inside `display()`. I think that should work.

Hope it helps!

Edit: Actually, I just realised that this solution is independent of whether ConfirmationBox extends DialogPane, since `window` is a Stage object and already includes the `showAndWait()` method.